# $\|\cdot\|_1 \leq \|\cdot\|_2 \leq \|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ for functions in $C([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Why does the following hold for continuous functions on $[0,1]$?

$\|\cdot\|_1 \leq \|\cdot\|_2 \leq \|\cdot\|_{\infty}$

Comment: It isn't. E.g. $\| (1,1) \|_1=2$, $\| (1,1) \|_2=\sqrt{2}$, $\| (1,1) \|_{\infty}=1$.

Comment: Which spaces are you considering?

Comment: It's the other way, at least on $\mathbb K^d$.

Comment: Consider providing more context to this question. It will help get better answers.

Comment: Whats $\mathbb{K}^d $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Holder's inequality (with $p=q=2$) one may deduce that for all $f\in C([0,1])$
$$
\Vert f\Vert_1=
\int\limits_0^1|f(x)|dx=
\int\limits_0^1|f(x)|\cdot |1| dx\leq
\left(\int\limits_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int\limits_0^1 |1|^2dx\right)^{1/2}=
\Vert f\Vert_2
$$
Moreover
$$
\Vert f\Vert_2=
\left(\int\limits_0^1|f(x)|^2dx\right)^{1/2}\leq
\left(\int\limits_0^1\Vert f\Vert_\infty^2 dx\right)^{1/2}=
\Vert f\Vert_\infty\left(\int\limits_0^1 1 dx\right)^{1/2}=\Vert f\Vert_\infty
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $x^{q/p}$ is convex for $q/p\ge1$, [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) yields
$$
\|f\|_p^q=\left(\int_I|f(x)|^p\mathrm{d}x\right)^{q/p}\le\int_I|f(x)|^{pq/p}\mathrm{d}x=\|f\|_q^q
$$
where $|I|=1$. Therefore, $\|f\|_p\le\|f\|_q$ when $p\le q$.

So on a space of measure $1$, $\|f\|_p$ is monotonically increasing in $p$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the equation should be read as $$\|\cdot \|_1 \lesssim \|\cdot \|_2 \lesssim \|\cdot \|_\infty,$$ i.e. $$\|\cdot \|_1 \leq C_1 \|\cdot \|_2 \leq  C_2 \|\cdot \|_\infty$$ for suitable constants $C_1>0$, $C_2>0$. In other words, $L^1 \supset L^2 \supset L^\infty$ with continuous immersions. This is true if you integrate on domains of finite measure, as follows from the Hölder inequality.

In the particular case of your question, it can be shown that you can take $C_1=C_2=1$.